# Battery suddenly not charging anymore

Tags: power-management, asus, battery

I have a relatively new ASUS F451MA. I had already updated the BIOS to the latest version before the problem appeared. I have opened up my laptop and tried to reset the battery by taking it out and putting it back again, to no avail. Then I removed 14.04 and did a fully new install of 15.04, but the stats are still the same:

```
native-path:          BAT0
vendor:               ASUSTeK
power supply:         yes
updated:              za 25 jul 2015 14:27:06 CEST (96 seconds ago)
has history:          yes
has statistics:       yes
battery
  present:             yes
  rechargeable:        yes
  state:               charging
  warning-level:       none
  energy:              0 Wh
  energy-empty:        0 Wh
  energy-full:         18,236 Wh
  energy-full-design:  32,625 Wh
  energy-rate:         0 W
  voltage:             11,25 V
  percentage:          0%
  capacity:            55,8958%
  technology:          lithium-ion
  icon-name:          'battery-caution-charging-symbolic'
```

Before trying to reset the battery and reinstalling Ubuntu I had tried lots of different possible solutions that I had found on this forum, but nothing worked, hence this post.

Comment: Can you verify that your problem is not caused by a hardware fault?

Comment: I guess not, although my gut feeling is that it's not a hardware problem, because it happened so suddenly. I also don't have a way of checking; I don't know anyone with a laptop with the same type of battery. Or is there another way?

Comment: also because it is very similar to this case: https://askubuntu.com/questions/409603/battery-issue-in-asus-with-ubuntu-12-04?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought: the battery charge settings usually **are** stored in the BIOS, and since you updated your BIOS it is possible that the settings maybe got overwritten (BIOS chips aren't the smartest things).

Sadly currently there doesn't seem to exist any Linux/Ubuntu tool that can manipulate that sort of information (unlike on Windows), which is kinda disappointing.
Still, could you go poking around in your BIOS? You should look for something named "Power Management" or "Battery Optimizer" or "Battery Saver" or something similar as the exact location and name changes from BIOS to BIOS and I'm unable to find a manual for your BIOS.
There should be a setting that controls the maximum allowed battery charge as a percentage - maybe it somehow got set to a horrible default 0% when you updated.

I wanted to post this as a comment, but ran out of space. :/